# Question about compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I know what compact sets are in $R^n$:A set S of real numbers is called compact if every sequence in S has a subsequence that converges to an element again contained in S.like i know similar definition is in every metric space(please correct me if i am wrong).my question is:every set in arbitrary metric space is compact, because i can take the sequence of elements in that set, and as a subsequence i can take only first element.Hence subsequence contains only one element so it is convergent subsequence, therefore every set in arbitrary metric space is compact.What is wrong in my logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong is that, no, you cannot just take the first element. A subsequence of a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$, where $(n_k)_{k\in\Bbb N}$ is a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers. And the sequence $1,1,1,1,\ldots$ is *not* strictly increasing.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong in your logic is your definition of subsequence. Note that with the way you think about subsequences, all of $\mathbb R^n$ and every one of its subsets would be "compact".

Comment: can you give some more information?i checked definition of subsequence in wikipedia.

Comment: I'm not a fan of that Wikipedia article, but I wonder what you read: it says "a subsequence is a sequence that can be derived from another sequence by deleting some or no elements without changing the order of the remaining elements". How do you get $x_1,x_1,x_1,\dots$ by deleting elements from $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$?

Comment: yeah you are right, i read wrong article, it is more about cs perspective rather than mathematical.so i found new article, which was correct.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence, this is the link of wrong article.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence this is true definition.thanks my bad.

Comment: But both articles say basically the same. A subsequence is what you get from a sequence by removing some elements. A key feature of a sequence is that it is *ordered* and that order should be preserved in the subsequence. Formally, you take an strictly increasing function $\sigma:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ to get a subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ given by  $x_{\sigma(n)}$.